# SVN authentication access with webdav

Tags: apache, svn, authentication, authorization

I am working with svn server with mod dav svn. and now I created auth user access to directory in the repository. I stuck when I try to limit access for some folder.
e.g: I have Project in repository called Adhown, inside project there are three folder called **stable**, **unstable**, and **testing** .

How can I limit those users can't commit to folder **stable** but able to commit to another folder using AuthzSVNAccess.

I already setup file, but I can't setting like that. can someone show me the right configuration?
this my configuration :

```
[groups]
developer = user1, user2, user3
guest = user4, user5, user6

[/]
* = r

[/path/to/my/folder]
developer = rw
```

thanks for your advance :)

Comment: What have you tried? What's the issue? You may want to check SVNBook BTW: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html

Comment: I already create auth file, but I don't know how to make limit access.

Comment: according to your current `authz` config: all authenticated users have **Read Only** access and those in Developer group have Read / Write access to some folder. Make sure that you use correct syntax to specify repository and repository path.

Comment: so what's wrong with my configuration? I still can't commit to [/path/to/my/folder]

Answer (score 0):

Sample from (already suggested) [SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.pathbasedauthz.html)

> Here's a simple example demonstrating a piece of the access
>   configuration which grants read access Sally, and read/write access to
>   Harry, for the path /branches/calc/bug-142 (and all its children) in
>   the repository calc:

```
[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142]
harry = rw
sally = r
```

Comment: hello Badger, I already follow that instruction. and this is my configuration :

[groups]
developer = user1, user2, user3
guest = user4, user5, user6

[/]
* = r

[/path/to/my/folder]
developer = rw

but it's doesn't work.

Comment: @adhown `[calc:/branches/calc/bug-142]`. Make sure you follow the correct syntax!

Answer (score 0):

the problem has been solved, I change authz file like this :

```
[groups]
developer = user1, user2, user3
guest = user4, user5, user6

[/]
developer = r
guest = r

[/path/to/my/folder]
developer = rw
```

when I used wildcard (*) is doesn't work.

thanks all

Comment: Beware! This form has side-effect, does you know and ready to it?

Comment: @LazyBadger do you mean that setting access to the root has a side-effect? Or what's the case?

Comment: @bahrep - without repository part (with SVNParentPath) path-only section means "this path in **any** served repository"